# SQL SELECT for the below req

Tags: sql, select

Looking for help in framing the Select statement for the below problem statement.

I have 2 tables, Assignment and the Target table. I'm looking for the following output as seen in the attached image. Can anyone help me with the SELECT statement.

[image]

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? Please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: You are better off just doing it by hand. What is the reason that E1's first and 3rd record have - and $0 but other ones have $100? Why does $500 associate with only E2's last record?

Comment: You want to **unpivot** your data. Search for that term and you might find an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to explain how 'Target' is derived in the result table, but on the face of it, something like this:

```
SELECT EN, SP FROM (
  SELECT EN, Q1 AS SP
  FROM Assignment

  UNION
  SELECT EN, Q2 AS SP
  FROM Assignment

  UNION
  SELECT EN, Q3 AS SP
  FROM Assignment

  UNION
  SELECT EN, Q4 AS SP
  FROM Assignment) A

INNER JOIN Target B
ON A.EN = B.EN
ORDER BY EN,SP;
```

Comment: I just edited the page to correct the column (typo).

Comment: I just edited the page to correct the column (typo). A little more explanation. First, its Sql Server (2012). This is a very complex query with multiple joins on 9 different tables and union of SELECTs as @Adam T has mentioned.  But I made it small just to attach this problem.  I could get the records if any of the Qs (Q1, Q2, Q3, Q4) have a valid value. If its Null, that record will not appear.  Secondly, if the value in more than one Q is the same, then the target should appear only for one record with the same Q value, as seen in the image added.  Both tables are joined by EN.